# Server crashed trying to restore wordpress multisite, images are not found pls help

Tags: htaccess

I had an issue with a server that was serious enough to have to take it completely offline and then rebuild the os.

I have gotten to the point where the new server is up and running. I have managed to get all the wordpress files and database files transfered over to the new server.

**The Problem**

For some reason wordpress is not finding any of the images stored in the wp-content/blogs.dir/... folder.

One thing I did notice is that the htaccess file was not copied over, so my best guess is because wordpress reroutes via /folders/ etc that this may be the problem.

I did take the distrubtion .htaccess file that I was able to find and added that into the site, but it is not working.

Is htaccess the problem?

If so how do I regenerate one that will work for the multisite subdomain setup?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the default .htaccess generated by Wordpress for Subdomain Multisite setup:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Let me know If this one doesn't work for you.

Comment: thanks for the file. This did not solve the problem of missing images but did solve other problems for me. I'm still investigating the images issue but getting closer.